# Supremum is the limit of some sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the attached from the Hubbards' multivariable calculus text. I am trying to prove (1.6.9) in particular: that is, if $M= \sup_{\textbf{c} \in C}f(\textbf{c})$ then there exists a sequence $i \mapsto \textbf{x}_i $ in $C$ such that $\lim_{i \to \infty} f(\textbf{x}_i) = M$. My attempt at a proof is as follows, where I proceed by contradiction:

Suppose that no such sequence existed, so that (negating the statement above) for every sequence in $C$, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that there is no integer $N$ which has $n>N \implies |f(\textbf{x}_i) - M| < \epsilon$. Consider all of the singleton sequences; that is, the sequence where $i \mapsto \textbf{x}_0 $ for some fixed $\textbf{x}_0 $ for each $i$. Then we have by the above development that, for each $\textbf{x}_0$ (corresponding to each singleton sequence in $C$), there is some $\epsilon_{\textbf{x}_0}$ such that $M-f(\textbf{x}_0) \geq \epsilon_{\textbf{x}_0}$...

This is where I run into a wall. I want to go further by saying that this implies that there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $M-f(\textbf{x}_0) \geq \epsilon$ for every $\textbf{x}_0$ which would contradict the definition of $M$, but it's not clear to me that what I've done allows for such an $\epsilon$. The set of $\epsilon_{\textbf{x}_0}$ is infinite and so I can't take a minimum, and the infimum may in general be $0$ which would contradict $\epsilon>0$. Am I supposed to use the compactness of $C$ somehow?

As I think about the question more, I think there is a way to construct the sequence in question by considering a sequence of $1/n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and using that $M$ is a supremum to observe that there must be some $f(\textbf{x}_0)$ such that $M-f(\textbf{x}_0)<1/n$ or else $M$ is not the supremum, but I'm hoping someone can rescue my original proof strategy somehow.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to prove the following statement:
$$
(P):\text{there is a sequence $\{x_i\}$ in $C$ such that $f(x_i)\to M$},
$$
and the strategy you've chosen is proof by contradiction, so we assume "not (P)" to start. "Not (P)" implies that for each sequence $a = \{x_i\}$ in $C$, the number
$$
\epsilon_a = \liminf_{i\to\infty}\big(M-f(x_i)\big)>0.\qquad(a = \{x_i\})
$$
Otherwise, $\epsilon_a = 0$, and hence there is a subsequence $a'$ of $a$ so that $M-f$ approaches $0$ along $a'$, contradicting "not (P)." Now consider the number
$$
\epsilon_0 := \inf\{\epsilon_a:a\}.
$$
I claim that $\epsilon_0>0$ by the assumption "not (P)." Otherwise, $\epsilon_0 = 0$, and there are sequences $a_1,a_2,\dots$ such that for each $n$, $\epsilon_{a_n} < 1/n$. By choosing points $x_n$, one from each of the tails of the sequences $a_n$, we can construct a new sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $f(x_n) \to M$. Since we assume "not (P)," this is impossible, so $\epsilon_0 > 0$.

As a consequence of $\epsilon_0>0$, for any sequence $\{x_i\}$,
$$
\liminf_{i\to\infty}\big(M-f(x_i)\big)\ge \epsilon_0 > 0.
$$
In particular, for all $i$ sufficiently large,
$$
0 < \epsilon_0 \le M-f(x_i).
$$
When we apply this to the constant sequences $\{x_i\} = \{x\}$, "$0<\epsilon_0\le M-f(x_i)$ for all $i$ sufficiently large" simply becomes $f(x)\le M-\epsilon_0 < M$ because $x_i = x$ for all $i$. This is finally the contradiction we aimed for because we contradicted the definition of $M$ as $\sup_Cf(x)$.

---

The direct strategy of proof for (P) is much simpler and easier to execute. By definition of $M$, for each $n$, there must exist a point $x_n\in C$ such that $M\ge f(x_n)>M-1/n$. By definition of the points $x_n$, $f(x_n)\to M$. This part of the argument of Theorem 1.6.9  doesn't have to do with the compactness of $C$—it is a consequence of the definition of the supremum of the set of numbers $\{f(x):x\in C\}$.

Comment: Agreed that the direct strategy is cleaner. But I'm not sure I follow your argument as to where I go wrong, and perhaps the crux is that I don't agree (or at least don't see) that you've negated the statement I want to prove correctly. Isn't the negation of (P) that for *every* sequence $x_i$ it is not true that $f(x_i)\to M$; that is, for for *every* sequence $x_i$ there exists an $\epsilon$ (which may depend on the given sequence) such that for all $N$ there is a $n>N$ with $|f(x_i) - M |> \epsilon$? You seem to write the first two quantifiers in a different order.

Comment: @EE18: If you want to negate it directly, then you are correct of course. For any sequence $a = (x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$, $f(x_i)$ does not converge to $M$. So there is a number $\epsilon_a>0$ so that $f(x_i)<M-\epsilon_a$. I claim you can take $\epsilon$ independent of $a$: consider $\inf\{\epsilon_a : a\}$. If this infimum is zero, then there is a sequence $x_i$ such that $f(x_i)\to M$ after all! (Notice how this is essentially recreating the direct strategy of proof with infima instead of suprema.) Otherwise, the infimum is positive, and we're back to what I said in the first part of my answer.

Comment: @EE18: But we don't need to jump through these hoops. If you see the forest for the trees, then it's clear that $\epsilon$ can be chosen independently of the sequence $a$. Because otherwise we're saying that you can choose points $x_i$ so that $f(x_i)$ is arbitrarily close to $M$, which is exactly what "(P)" says, and "(P)" is exactly what we are negating.

Comment: Those two comments really help tidy things up for me. Last query though, with regard to your statement that "If this infimum is zero, then there is a sequence $x_i$ such that $f(x_i) \to M$ after all". I want to make sure I understand why. If it's $0$ then we've shown that for every $\epsilon >0$ there is some sequence  such that eventually $M-f(x_i)<\epsilon$ or else that $\epsilon$ is the infimum of $\{\epsilon_a\}$. But then "for every $\epsilon >0$ there is some sequence  such that eventually $M-f(x_i)<\epsilon$" is the definition of $M$ being the limit of some sequence. Is that correct?

Comment: @EE18: If the infimum is zero, then we can even build a sequence $x_i$ so that $f(x_i)\to M$. We just take points $x_i$ in the tails of sequences $a_i$ such that $\epsilon_{a_i} < 1/i$. By construction, $f(x_i)>M-1/i$. I think the way you worded it in your comment is a little awkward, but it's essentially the right idea.

Comment: Noted, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @EE18: Happy it helps :-)

Comment: The second sentence of the answer, beginning "You have to realize ..." is wrong. The negation of (P) tells you that, for each sequence, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that ....; it does not guarantee the existence of an $\epsilon>0$ that works simultaneously for all sequences. (If the "proof" in the first two paragraphs were correct, it would also show that there is a constant sequence converging to $M$.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Apologies for the tricky wording. I expanded on what I wrote initially. I hope it's clearer now what I meant by there being an $\epsilon>0$ that works simultaneously for all sequences.